# App Center automate branch deployments without manually cloning configuration

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

The issue I have is at the moment if I push a new branch to GitHub I have to go to App Center and manually clone/configure the build for this branch.

I would like to have a common build configuration for let's say all branches prefixed with `featured` that would be used in App Center and trigger a build on push.

Is it possible to deploy new branches on push without manually configuring/cloning the build in App Center?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible via AppCenter CLI - here is an example script:
[Related discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-cli/issues/690)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
CURRENT_BRANCH=$(git branch --show-current)
OWNER_NAME="XXXXXXX"
APP_NAME_IOS="xxxxxx"
APP_NAME_ANDROID="xxxxxx"

function clone_build {
  local current_branch_encoded=$(sed 's/\//\%2f/g' <<< $1)  # replace strings in branch name, change "/" to "%2f" and others non url friendly
  local os=$2
  local app=$3
  local token=$4
  local from_clone=$5

  printMsg "Cloning app: ${app}, branch: ${CURRENT_BRANCH}"
  printMsg "Validating if AppCenter config is currently defined"
  if [ "$(curl -sL -w "%{http_code}" -X GET "https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/${OWNER_NAME}/${app}/branches/${current_branch_encoded}/config" -H "accept: application/json" -H "X-API-Token:${token}" -o /dev/null)" = 200 ]; then
    printMsg "AppCenter config already defined"
  else
    if [ "$(curl -sL -w "%{http_code}" -X POST "https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/${OWNER_NAME}/${app}/branches/${current_branch_encoded}/config" -H "accept: application/json" -H "X-API-Token:${token}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"cloneFromBranch\": \"${from_clone}\"}" -o /dev/null)" = 200 ]; then
      printMsg "AppCenter config cloned successfully"
    else
      printMsg "AppCenter config cloned failed"
    fi
  fi

  echo ""
}

# Android
clone_build $CURRENT_BRANCH "Android" ${APP_NAME_ANDROID} "$API_TOKEN" "$CLONE_BRANCH"
appcenter build queue --branch $CURRENT_BRANCH --app ${OWNER_NAME}/${APP_NAME_ANDROID}

# IOS
clone_build $CURRENT_BRANCH "iOS" ${IOS_APP_NAME} "$API_TOKEN" "$CLONE_BRANCH"
appcenter build queue --branch $CURRENT_BRANCH --app ${OWNER_NAME}/${IOS_APP_NAME}
```